# Highlight cell with RGB colour listed in cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to highlight a cell with the colour specified by a hex code written in cells I4 and J4. I have a table set up, I'm just not sure on how to get this code to loop through from I4 to the last row of the table?

I've modified this code from another I use but that is on a sheet with a set range of 3 cells that change.

```
Sub BasicHome()
    Dim lngColor As Long
    Dim ES As Worksheet, _
    R As Long, i As Long, WB As ThisWorkbook

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = ActiveSheet
    
    lngColor = RGB(Cells(4, 17), Cells(4, 18), Cells(4, 19))
    With Range("I4").Interior
        .Color = lngColor
        ActiveWorkbook.Colors(.ColorIndex) = lngColor
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub BasicAway()
    Dim lngColor As Long
    Dim ES As Worksheet, _
    R As Long, i As Long, WB As ThisWorkbook

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = ActiveSheet
    
    lngColor = RGB(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 21), Cells(4, 22))
    With Range("J4").Interior
        .Color = lngColor
        ActiveWorkbook.Colors(.ColorIndex) = lngColor
    End With
    
End Sub


Sub BasicSetFontColor()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim colours As Range
    Set colours = Range("I4:I4", "J4:J4")
    For Each Cell In colours
        Cell.Font.Color = BorW(Cell.Interior.Color)
    Next Cell
End Sub


Function BorW(RGB As Long) As Long
    Dim R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer
    R = (RGB And &HFF)
    G = (RGB And &HFF00&) / 256
    B = (RGB And &HFF0000) / 65536
    BorW = vbWhite
    If R * 0.3 + G * 0.59 + B * 0.11 > 128 Then BorW = vbBlack
End Function

Sub MasterColourBasic()
    
    Call BasicHome
    Call BasicAway
    Call BasicSetFontColor
    
End Sub
```

Running this fills the cells as below, but currently will only work for cells I4 and J4

[image]

Comment: Aren't you always getting either `vbWhite` or `vbBlack` depending on what the previous color was?

Comment: No, I'll add an image into my original post so you can see what it does

Comment: My bad, was too focused on the colors that I didn't see the `.Font`

Comment: No problem, I just need to work out how to get it to loop through!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'd loop until the last row:

```
Sub BasicHome(row As Long)
    Dim lngColor As Long
    Dim ES As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long, i As Long, WB As Workbook

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = ActiveSheet
    
    lngColor = RGB(Cells(row, 17), Cells(row, 18), Cells(row, 19))
    With Range("I" & row).Interior
        .Color = lngColor
        'ActiveWorkbook.Colors(.ColorIndex) = lngColor 'I commented this since it threw an error during my testing with different colors
'I don't see the need to change Excel's chosen color to it each row either
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub BasicAway(row As Long)
    Dim lngColor As Long
    Dim ES As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long, i As Long, WB As Workbook

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = ActiveSheet
    
    lngColor = RGB(Cells(row, 20), Cells(row, 21), Cells(row, 22))
    With Range("J" & row).Interior
        .Color = lngColor
        'ActiveWorkbook.Colors(.ColorIndex) = lngColor
    End With
    
End Sub


Sub BasicSetFontColor(row As Long)
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim colours As Range
    Set colours = Range("I" & row & ":J" & row)
    For Each Cell In colours
        Cell.Font.Color = BorW(Cell.Interior.Color)
    Next Cell
End Sub


Function BorW(RGB As Long) As Long
    Dim R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer
    R = (RGB And &HFF)
    G = (RGB And &HFF00&) / 256
    B = (RGB And &HFF0000) / 65536
    BorW = vbWhite
    If R * 0.3 + G * 0.59 + B * 0.11 > 128 Then BorW = vbBlack
End Function

Sub MasterColourBasic()
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    lRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
'Adding Variables for elapsed Time
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim TimeTaken As String
    
    StartTime = Timer 'I was testing whether it's faster to loop the subs or loop in the subs
    
    For i = 4 To lRow
        BasicHome i 'Call subName is deprecated
        BasicAway i
        BasicSetFontColor i
    Next i
    
    TimeTaken = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    Debug.Print "This macro MasterColourBasic lasted " & TimeTaken & " minutes" 
'this was 6 seconds for 40000 rows
End Sub
```

The test about looping in the subs instead of looping the subs, the end result was 6 seconds for each so I guess for this case, it doesn't really matter. You can comment/delete the time-stuff.

If anything is unclear still, let me know!